# How can I clean up app.yaml leaving only top page for each script?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need help with my `app.yaml` and url management. I have the scripts `ting.py`, `searchandler.py` and `toplawfirms.py`. I created `ting.py` first and I have in `app.yaml`

```
- url: /.*
  script: ting.py
```

and all other pages are declared in `ting.py`. But I think I made a mistake with `searchhandler.py` and `toplawfirms.py` by not making them second level. Is there a way now to have in `app.yaml` only the three scripts so that my `app.yaml` would look like

```
...

- url: /???
  script: searchhandler.py

- url: /???
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /.*
  script: ting.py

...
```

so that I can declare all other pages in their scripts?

This is what I have now:

```
application: ting-1
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: incoming.py 
  login: admin  

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico

- url: /image
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /imageupload
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /imagesave
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /imageresize
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /displayimage
  script: toplawfirms.py  

- url: /histogram
  script: toplawfirms.py  

- url: /testurlopen
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /printdb
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /cropimage
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /jquerytest
  script: toplawfirms.py 

- url: /urlopenppp
  script: toplawfirms.py

- url: /deleteone 
  script: toplawfirms.py 

- url: /enterppp 
  script: toplawfirms.py 

- url: /saveppp 
  script: toplawfirms.py 


- url: /searchhandler
  script: searchhandler.py  

- url: /site
  script: searchhandler.py


- url: /searchall
  script: searchall.py


- url: /.*
  script: ting.py

inbound_services:
- mail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a single WSGI app in `ting.py`, and add all the handlers for all your URLs to it. Then delete all but the `/.*` mapping.

Comment: Should I remove `def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()` from `searchhandler.py` and `toplawfirms.py` and put all handlers to `ting.py` OR remove `searchhandler.py` and `toplawfirms.py` and transfer all the code in them to `ting.py` and use only `ting.py`?

Comment: Either one; which you prefer depends on your app. In the former case, you should import `searchhandler` and `toplawfirms` in ting.py in order to reference their handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I use handlers from different modules. I just put this at the end of everthing then above I can do whatever else:

```
...
# All other URLs use main.app
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
inbound_services:
- xmpp_message
- mail
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
- remote_api: on

error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: setuptools
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
- name: django
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
- name: webob
  version: latest
```